# Reading emails with MAPI in PHP?

Tags: php, email, exchange-server, mapi

As you know Microsoft Exchange Server uses a proprietary protocol called [MAPI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MAPI).
Is that possible to read emails from the Ms exchange with that protocol in PHP.
I found an extension [PHP-MAPI](https://community.zarafa.com/php-ext/).
But i guess it is only for [Zarafa server](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zarafa_(software)) or something like that. Correct me if i am wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Extended MAPI can only be used from C++ or Delphi.
You can use [Redemption](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption) (I am its author): it is an Extended MAPI wrapper usable from any language that supports `IDispatch` based COM objects). Keep in mind however that the MAPI system must be installed (which means Outlook must be installed).
In case of Redemption, you probably want [RDOSession](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/rdosession.htm).`LogonHostedExchangeMailbox` (it creates a one-off profile that points to the specified mailbox using online mode).

Comment: So, i can use mapi/http(mapi over http) in php via an extension which uses C++. Is that correct?

Comment: MAPI over HTTP is just a mechanism that MSEMS provider uses to talk to Exchange. Extended MAPi is a set of client interfaces (IMAPISession, IAddrBook, IMessage, etc.) that are exposed regardless of the particular store provider.

Answer (score 0):

Every Microsoft environment offered the ["Microsoft Exchange Webservices" (EWS)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dd877045(v=exchg.140).aspx) which you can use in PHP in order to perform a wide range of options. So if I would be you I would start looking into EWS.

Here are some starting points:

- [Get started with EWS Managed API client applications](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn567668(v=exchg.150).aspx)
- [How to: Send email messages by using EWS in Exchange](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn600292(v=exchg.150).aspx)
- [How to: Respond to email messages by using EWS in Exchange](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn617213(v=exchg.150).aspx)

A more detailed PHP specified answer can be found here:

- [How To Connect Exchange Server With PHP](http://phpflow.com/php/how-to-connect-exchange-server-with-php/)
- [How to Read inbox Mails From Exchange Server](http://phpflow.com/php/how-to-read-inbox-mails-from-exchange-server/)

Comment: The company doesnt work with ews,imap,pop etc. They work only with MAPI. That is why i asked it.

Comment: I don´t think that information you got from them is correct. If they use Microsoft office for MAC then they have EWS already in place (more infos [here](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Access-your-account-using-a-Mac-e96367c3-3f39-4d16-91a3-410cc075d29b)), otherwise it wouldn´t work. It is also not really usefull or supported to disable EWS as you will run in a wide range of other issues.

Comment: I got that information from them. It doesnt work for security reasons.